# Can I confirm my identity at the polling station without taking off the mask?

Tags: voting, covid-19, ukraine, public-health

My country has an upcoming elections soon.
On the polling station I will need to confirm my identity with photo ID; this implies taking off the mask in a crowded place.

I take social-distancing measures very seriously; I wear my mask and plastic gloves before going out from home, never take it off outdoors, and dispose it only back home. So I'm concerned that taking off the mask could undermine my effort of social distancing.

My question is two-fold:

1. Are there any regulations that allow me to confirm my identity without the need of taking off the mask?
2. If not (which I suppose), what are the recommendations of WHO or other relevant institutions in this regard?

I'm mainly interested to know the up-to-date regulations in Ukraine, but answers describing successful policies developed by other countries would be appreciated as well.

---

#### Further details

The new Ukrainian photo ID contains biometric information (including fingerprint, I believe), but I'm sure that most polling stations in Ukraine are not equipped with fingerprint readers.

Throughout the last 6 months, I was in a situation when I needed to confirm my identity just once. when I re-issued an ATM card in a local bank. It was an almost empty office, and only few people were  I briefly took off the mask while holding my breath so that the officer confirmed that my face matches the photo ID. Obviously, this would not work in a crowded place like a polling station, and this is my primary concern.

Comment: I would check the local news as there is likely to be some coverage on how to handle this.